# SoapUI - automate mock services in bat file

Tags: soap, service, soapui

How would I run multiple mock services with a single mockservicerunner on the same port?

I have tried this:

"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\mockservicerunner.bat" -m"Service1 MockService" -m"Service2 MockService" "C:\Path\my-soapui-project.xml"

Only the first service in the first parameter is run.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\mockservicerunner.bat" "C:\Path\my-soapui-project.xml"

Or

./mockservicerunner.bat "ProjectPath"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that like running two mock services on same port.

Rather try to have one mock service with some dispatching logic that will send different mock responses based on your request.

Answer (score 0):

The Mock service runner can only run one project at a time, you'll have to use multiple instances of the runner.

http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18642